# i3 combining multiple modes (stacked, split, tabbed)

Tags: i3-window-manager

I want to be able to ideally have a vertical split and in one of the split windows, initiate another window which is tabbed. So, it would be two split containers with multliple tabbed windows in the end. I know that mod + w would be tabbed mode. However, once I do press that, the splits disappear. I can't find anything regarding this in the user's guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If think what you are asking is achieved in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wx0eNaGzAZU) video. To understand how i3 works, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWA8Pl57UBY) video discusses the data structure used to handle split containers. If you are familiar with a BST or the tree data structure in general you should understand what is going on. If not and you are intersted, you can search Wikipedia for the Tree data structure to learn more about it.

Comment: Perfect. It would be awesome if I could just switch to some other mode w/o actually creating another window.

Comment: Don't *only* put references to videos here...