# How do I stack windows in a container positioned in the right/bottom part of a workspace?

Tags: i3-window-manager, swaywm

I want to be able to organise my windows as follows:

```
 ---------------------
 | term  |===========|
 |       |  editor   |
 |       |           |
 ---------------------
```

where I try to illustrate stacked windows by the equal signs in the upper part of the right container.
I am able to split the workspace horisontally so that I have two windows beside each other. When I am focused in the right window and press mod+s for a stacked organisation, I lose the horisontal split and the entire workspace is stacked.

On my rotated screen I want to be able to organise my windows according to the figure below:

```
-----------
| editor  |
|         |  
|         |  
|=========|
|=========|
| term    |
 ---------
```

I am able to split the workspace vertically so that I have two windows on top of each other. When I am focused in the lower window and press mod+s for a stacked organisation, I lose the vertical split and the entire workspace is stacked.

The i3-documentation says:
"The terminology is "window" for a container that actually contains an X11 window (like a terminal or browser) and "split container" for containers that consist of one or more windows." ( https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html at the end of section 2.1)

How do I tell i3 that I want a window to be a split container? How can I stack windows in a right/lower container?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it appears that I need to add a middle-step.

```
 ---------------------
 | term  |           |
 |       |  editor   |
 |       |           |
 ---------------------
```

From the layout above, focus the right window with the editor. Press mod+v to split it vertically. Press mod+enter to add a terminal window. The window then becomes a split container.

```
 ---------------------
 | term  |  editor   |
 |       |-----------|
 |       | terminal  |
 ---------------------
```

then press mod+s for the editor and terminal to be stacked in the right split. A bit clumsy, but okay.

stacking and tabbing seems to operate on OPEN windows in the EXISTING split container while vertical and horisontal splits operates on FUTURE windows and CREATES a split container from the current window. (The parent container can be focused using mod+a.)

I figured it out with the help of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWA8Pl57UBY in the answer to this question: [i3 combining multiple modes (stacked, split, tabbed)](https://superuser.com/questions/904939/i3-combining-multiple-modes-stacked-split-tabbed)